# What is the role of the CX in 42h DOS function in assembly Language?

Tags: assembly, x86-16

```
    mov ah, 42h
    mov bx, address
    xor cx, cx
    xor dx, dx     
    mov al, 2     
    int 21h
```

This is the Code I wrote to move file pointer

What's actually the Role of cx register? when I do mov cx, 1. It created file with the size of 15mb -_-. Basically, I am not understanding what actually cx is doing.

Comment: CX register holds the upper 16 bits of the lseek offset … here you are setting it to zero. DX is the lower 16 bits .  42h means you are seeking from the end of the file.

Comment: http://spike.scu.edu.au/~barry/interrupts.html#ah42